# how to insert cakephp image code into form?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I got a insert form. I would like to insert the below code into the form.

```
<?php
    echo $html->image("slide_03.jpg", array(
        "alt" => "Event Banner",
        'class' => '',
        ));
?>
```

In my view layer I want the the image to be display. However, the image did not display and got this code in my view layer instead

```
image("slide_03.jpg", array( "alt" => "Event Banner", 'class' => '', )); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In CakePHP 2.x you have to use `$this->Html->image()`. `$html->image()` was used in previous CakePHP versions and no longer works in CakePHP 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

In general (not just for images) you can set option `after` or `before` if you want additional html elements near of your input element.

As you see from sample below you can combine input options with `$this->Html->image()`.

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
        'before' => $this->Html->image(),
        'after' => $this->Html->image(),
));
```

More details about options on [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options).